# How to trigger Bootstrap popover in my react app

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-popover

In jQuery we usually trigger a popover like below :

```
$(".font-family").popover({ 
   html: true, 
   animation: true, 
   placement: 'auto top'
});
```

component :

```
this.state.data.map((element, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index} style={{ "fontFamily":element.value }} data-fontFamily={element.value} id={element.name} data-content={element.message}
                    ref={(ref) => this.fontFamily = ref}
                    className = ".font-family"
                    >
                  {element.name}
                </div>
            );
});
```

but I want to implement it in react, I know call those codes in ComponentDidMount() will work, but I want to do it in react way.

```
$(this.refs.fontFamily).popover({  
            react: true 
});
```

by using this it works but I'm sick of using $ to trigger popover in react.

note : I don't want to add extra libraries like react-bootstrap for this case and need a React-based solution.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is using React with jquery to trigger bootstrap popover or can use React-bootstrap popover.

[Check the demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-popover)

We can use `ReactDOM.createPortal` in react new version(16.5).

Comment: I guess it should be something like this
setTimeout(() => {
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
}, 0)

Answer (score 1):

Basically two steps to have a popover with Bootstrap:

1. Render an element with popover properties, `data-toggle="popover"`, `title`, and `data-content`
2. Enable popovers via JavaScript

In React, `render()` for step 1 and `componentDidMount()` for step 2

For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Suppose you have already included bootstrap required JS files
    window.jQuery('#popoverExample').popover();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        id="popoverExample"
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-lg btn-danger"
        data-toggle="popover"
        title="Popover title"
        data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
        Click to toggle popover
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

[Here](https://bootstrap-4-react.com/#documentation/components/popover) is one simple way by using a library. It essentially does the above for you. Not really needed if you don't want the library.